# Clear all currently defined vim macros

Tags: vim, macros

I have a vim macro that I keep mistyping, usually when I'm trying to save something so I do it quickly and I can't work out what keys I pressed. It is annoying as it pastes some irrelevant bash code into my file so I have to undo the erroneous pasting which also undos the last thing I typed that I do want.

I was looking for a way to either list the currently defined macros (so I can redefine the offending one), or a way to clear out them completely. I only use macros in the very short term so I don't mind losing them all.

Cheers

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Macros**

What is mostly called a macro in vim is initiated with <kbd>@</kbd> and a letter. It executes the contents of a register with the said letter as its name.

**List the register contents**

`:reg`

You can clear the register a with

`:let @a = ''`

---

Sometimes mappings or abbreviations are confused for macros, therefore here is some information about them.

**List mappings**

all mappings

`:map`

all mappings that start with \

`:map \`

normal mode

`:nmap`

insert mode

`:imap`

visual mode

`:vmap`

command mode

`:cmap`

**List abbreviations**

all abbreviations

`:abbr`

all abbreviations starting with email

`:abbr email`

insert mode

`:iabbr`

command mode

`:cabbr`

You can use `:verbose` before the previous commands to get more info about where the mapping/abbreviation was last set, as in `:verbose nmap`. These commands also show all the mappings that have been set by plugins and other configuration files.

**Removing a mapping/abbreviation**

(only a couple of modes listed here, you should be able to remove one just for a certain mode just like with the listing commands above.)

insert mode, remove a mapping that is defined as \:

`:iunmap \\`

normal mode:

`:nunmap \\`

remove an abbreviation defined as email:

`:unabbr email`

insert mode:

`:iunabbr email`

**Clear mappings/abbreviations**

I wouldn't recommend clearing all mappings/abbreviations since you would lose everything your plugins have mapped/abbreviated. However, you can clear mappings by putting the letter <kbd>c</kbd> after the above listing command, as in `:imapc` to clear insert mode mappings. Abbreviations can be cleared with `:abclear`, or just for insert mode `:iabclear` and just for command mode `:cabclear`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was a macro in the  end (@w which could easily get typed when saving!). I've cleared it now, cheers

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how exactly do you save if you might mistype @w? And sorry for assuming you meant something else, it's just that even vim help guides you to key-mapping section if you look for :h macro. I edited the reply so that the macro part is at the start of the answer.

Comment: I save in vim with :w, how do you save a file? As you found, the vim help directed me to the wrong place, hence the question.

Comment: I just found it odd since I have extremely rarely typed @ by accident even though I do mistype lots of other characters.

While coding, I usually have a mapping for <BS>w that saves the file and runs a syntax checker on it.

Comment: well I'm on a british keyboard so the @ key is right next to the : key

Answer (score 6):

To clear a single macro - record over it - with nothing.

For your situation in normal mode you'd just type "qwq".

- q to begin to record a macro
- w to set the buffer space to w
- q again to save the (now empty) macro

Verify with :reg[ister] w

This is only slightly quicker than :let @w = '' but for myself is easier to remember.